# Servlet request with pattern < IS( > or < IF( > getting blocked apache/adobe experience manager

Tags: java, apache, aem

We are calling AEM servlets from our frontend code but seeing in PROD environment requests with content like IS(something) or IF(something) is getting blocked. Any idea from where it is getting blocked? Thanks in advance. Example request - https://url.com/bin/project/getval?ref=1234-PUN**IS(CARTHAGE)**-XYZ

Comment: Most likely, you have some kind of Web Aplication Firewall in place that's treating this as a SQL Injection attempt or some kind of XSS attack. Could be something at CDN level, could be `mod_security` on Apache. What's the response code and body?

Comment: Indeed, this being the production environment, there are many other layers affecting what AEM receives. If this request works locally (where more likely you do not have a dispatcher in front), then is not AEM which is blocking the requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found the reason of this behavior. There was a Akamai Web Filter configured which was considering this request as a script/ attack. That is why it was blocking it. Just thought of putting it here so that it might help anyone else.